# css style for div tag alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to display 2 div tag and ul list in same line.Now looking one by one.
Now my tags are looking as

[image]

But I want as my drawn layout.My css and html is given below.

[image]
m is the menu listed one by one.but a,s,a are in same line

```css
.address {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:right;
 display:inline;
}
.address p{
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
div.down  {
 display:inline;
 margin-left:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.list-inline1 ul{
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul.list-inline {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.list-inline li {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:10px;
}
ul.list-inline li a {
 display:inline;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footercolor">
         <div class="down">
                  
                    <ul  class="list-inline1 ">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="product.php"><b>Product</b></a> <!--product -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.php"><b>Contact Us</b></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="login.php"><b>Login</b></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                
                </div>
                 <ul class="list-inline ">
  <li><a href=><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="address">
        <p>sample<br>trail<br>demo1<br>address</p>
  </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Give `float: left;` to ul, m and a div.  And give a small widths to these to fit exactly to width of the screen

Comment: If you don't need to support [very old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block), in most cases it is way much easier to use `display: inline-block;` on blocks you need side-by-side than floating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add width's to your floated containers. Plus i took off margin's for the styling of the elements would cleaner. And how I got width of 30% to the containers is by doing the number of columns divided by 100%. Then you have think about margin and padding you have put on the elements.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tygdqojg/)**

---

[**UPDATED JSFIDDLE without bullets**](http://jsfiddle.net/tygdqojg/2/)

---

```
.address {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    width: 30%;
}
.address p {
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #000;
}
div.down {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.list-inline1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.list-inline {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
ul.list-inline li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.list-inline li a {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: list-style-type: none; is not working I dont want bullet in list.

Comment: @user3386779 here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tygdqojg/2/ without bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link add column class for each

```
.column{
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;


}
.footercolor{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/xecigodeje/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score -1):

your elements should have a width attribute, otherwise they take up 100% a they are actually block elements.

Also try setting 'display' to 'inline-block'

```
.adress, div.down, ul.list-inline {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30%
}
.address {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
}
.address p{
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
div.down  {
    margin-left:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.list-inline1 ul{
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul.list-inline {
  margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:50px;
}
ul.list-inline li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
ul.list-inline li a {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just make the structure. put the elements in the divs with class="column" (e.g.) and add the css:

```
.column {position: relative; float: left; margin-right: 20px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding float:left; and margin-right:10px

```
ul.list-inline li {
display:inline;
margin-right:10px;
list-style:none;
padding:10px;
float:left;
}
```